# Make Code Analysis stop warning about a certain variable name

Tags: c#, .net, code-analysis

I have a variable named like `allowedZHs`. `ZH` is a domain specific acronym. `ZHs` is its plural form. I would like to continue using that plural form. I find it much more expressive than the "correct" form "`Zhs`".
I tried to tell Code Analysis this by adding a [Code Analysis Dictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb514188.aspx). This works fine for the singular form "`ZH`" but it doesn't work for the plural form.
I still get warning [CA1704](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb264492.aspx).

I tried adding it as a recognized word and adding it as an acronym:

```
<Dictionary>
  <Words>
    <Recognized>
      <Word>ZHs</Word>
    </Recognized>
  </Words>
  <Acronyms>
    <CasingExceptions>
      <Acronym>ZHs</Acronym>
    </CasingExceptions>
  </Acronyms>
</Dictionary>
```

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Comment: "ID" vs "Id" "IDs" vs "Ids". Is one really more expressive. Perhaps you should add the whole variable name in your dictionary <Word>allowedZHs</Word>

Comment: @LastCoder: Thanks for the suggestion. That doesn't work either. The existing warning doesn't go away and additionally, I will get another one (CA1702)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The bad news is that there's no way to use the dictionary to allow plural acronyms in older FxCop versions.  (See, for example, Kevin Blasko's answer at http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/eu/vstscode/thread/56af1337-895d-47ec-ac72-71cf0316ea60.)  The good news is that the version that ships with VS 2012 allows them out-of-the-box, so you won't even need to touch the dictionary when you eventually upgrade.

Comment: Thanks for the link. While it's a pity I can't fix it in VS2010, I am glad that it is fixed in the latest version.